# how to make gif image by two bitmaps in android

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif

I just want to  make animated gif image from 2 bitmap images which i will get from camera and want to mail that gif image.

Comment: I dont know how to convert bitmaps (framed) to animated gif

Comment: @Iphone_bharat did u get the solution. If yes then please share the code.

Answer (score 4):

There is native library for that http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html#gifflen

> I've written a small native lib for Android to do color quantization (from 2-256 colors) of a Bitmap and save the result as a frame in an animated GIF (you can add as many frames as you like).
>   You may hack and slash the library code as you wish to fit your needs. The color quantizer used is Anthony Dekker's NeuQuant, with some modifications made by me.

For a java based library try http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/12/04/j2me-animated-gif-encoder/

> Usage is quite straightforward, and it requires these steps:
>       Instantiate your AnimatedGifEncoder object
>       Start it, by passing an OutputStream as argument (e.g.: a ByteArrayOutputStream)
>       Add your Image objects by using addFrame() method
>       Finalize it by calling finish()