# How to create a gif from camera pictures in android

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, gif

I am working on a functionality which allow the user to click the photo for as many times as they want and then create a gif from those photos.If anyone has any idea regarding this then it will be helpful for me.Please help me out with this.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331437/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-jpegs-in-android-development or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515350/how-to-make-gif-image-by-two-bitmaps-in-android might it help you , if it works for you let me know.

Comment: Try ffmpeg lib for this.

Answer (score 0):

To use this function, do the following then you can save the file into SDcard.

```
    public void convertGif(String imagepath){

     FileOutputStream outStream = null;
     try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(/sdcard/generate_gif/test.gif);//This is storage path of gif
        outStream.write(generateGIF(imagepath));
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public byte[] generateGIF(String path) {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        bitmaps.add(path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
        encoder.start(bos);
        for (Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps) {
            encoder.addFrame(bitmap);
        }
        encoder.finish();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Response from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20277649/2382438)

Comment: I need to take the picture from camera then create a gif from the captured image.I had already taken the picture from camera and stored it into one directory but now how can i create the gif from it this is my question

Comment: So put above code in one method and pass path to that method for usages

Comment: what is getBitmapArray() method?